How to have a BottomNavigationBar show on more than just the main screens, but not all screens?
Currently it only shows on main screens. I can only get it working on either ALL screens or only main screens... I need to be able to choose which screens to show the BottomNavigationBar on.
I now observe the routing in main.dart and handle the rest of the navigation bar logic in a file I call NavigationConduit.

The navigation bar shows 5 main screens.
The bar should also remain visible on some other screens (such as settings, accessed from a main screen).
But there are some screens where it should not be visible (such as change password screen).

I have a feeling the RouteObserver is not working properly, already not on the main screens... What am I doing wrong in this approach?
Is there a better way, without having to put code in every screen's initState and dispose?
This is my main.dart, reduced to only show related code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/navigation_conduit.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/profile/settings_1_overview.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/auth/change_password_1_current.dart';

final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
      home: const NavigationConduit(),
      routes: {
        '/screens/profile/settings_1_overview': (context) => const SettingsOverview(),
        '/screens/auth/change_password_1_current': (context) => const ChangePasswordScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

And then this is my navigation_conduit.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/home/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/overview/overview.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/scanner/scanner.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/favorites/favorites_overview.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/profile/user_profile.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/profile/settings_1_overview.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/auth/change_password_1_current.dart';

class NavigationConduit extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavigationConduit({super.key});

  @override
  _NavigationConduitState createState() => _NavigationConduitState();
}

class _NavigationConduitState extends State<NavigationConduit> with RouteAware {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  bool _showBottomNavBar = true;

  final List<Widget> _screens = [
    const HomeScreen(),
    const Overview(),
    const Scanner(),
    const FavoritesOverview(),
    const UserProfile(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    if (_selectedIndex == index) {
      Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
        _showBottomNavBar = true;
      });
    }
  }


  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final ModalRoute? route = ModalRoute.of(context);
    setState(() {
      _showBottomNavBar = _shouldShowBottomNavBar(route);
    });
  }


  bool _shouldShowBottomNavBar(Route<dynamic>? route) {
    if (route == null) return true;
    final currentRouteName = route.settings.name ?? '';
    print('Checking route: $currentRouteName');
    return ![
      '/screens/profile/settings_6_info',
      '/screens/auth/change_password_1_current',
    ].contains(currentRouteName);
  }


  @override
  void didPush() {
    super.didPush();
    setState(() {
      _showBottomNavBar = _shouldShowBottomNavBar(ModalRoute.of(context));
    });
  }


  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    super.didPopNext();
    setState(() {
      _showBottomNavBar = _shouldShowBottomNavBar(ModalRoute.of(context));
    });
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }


  String getIconAsset(int index, bool isSelected) {}
  // This gets all the images connected to the right icons


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _screens[_selectedIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: _showBottomNavBar
          ? Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFA4A4A4), width: 1.0),
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: List.generate(5, (index) {
            bool isSelected = _selectedIndex == index;
            return IconButton(
              icon: Image.asset(
                getIconAsset(index, isSelected),
                width: 24.0,
                height: 24.0,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _onItemTapped(index);
              },
            );
          }),
        ),
      )
          : null,
    );
  }
}


For that , either you can use library or implement persistent bottom bar by yourself
Library :- https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar
For research purpose :- https://medium.com/go-with-flutter/30-flutter-tips-ft30-persistent-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-6b6028dd6f99

I have a feeling the package persistent_bottom_nav_bar is not maintained well, since a fix for a major bug in the new Flutter is already waiting for over a month in a fork, pending merge. I did try it nonetheless - with the fork - but had the same problem with that package, with the navigation bar either showing everywhere, or only on the main screens. There must be something that's blocking the logic of 'on and off'...

Have you tried it’s v2 version ? https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2

Turns out I only had to add "rootNavigator: true" to the Navigator.of(context) whenever I wanted to hide the navigation bar on the next screen.
